# SharePoint monitoring parameters

Tags: sharepoint-server

Would like to configure monitoring parameters for SharePoint servers.Which are parameters should be configured for SharePoint?

Comment: This is pretty broad, can you provide additional info re your goals for monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

**Some of SharePoint Monitoring Parameters**

- Network Monitor
- Database Connectivity and availability Monitor.
- Data Grows Monitor.
- Ports Monitor
- Resource Monitor

  - CPU Utilization.
  - Memory.
  - Hard Disk.
- Page Request time Monitor.
- User Activity Monitor
- Service Applications.
- Logs Monitor.
- Workflow Services Monitor.
- SharePoint Windows Services like Timer Service, distributed cache...etc.
- IIS, Application Pools, Security Token App Pool Monitor.

Check also, [Plan for monitoring in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/monitoring-planning)